# Null Pointer at foreign key

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I'm using MySQL and Hibernate. I've added record to `Receiving` table and have `id` and `barcode` fields as foreign keys in `transaction` table `rcid` and `barcode`.

When I search a specific record using id:

```
int id =(Integer)defaultTableModel.getValueAt(jReceivingsTable.getSelectedRow(),0);

Receivings receivings = manager.searchReceivingsId(id);
```

that doesn't `null`, printing `id` return appropriate value so why I'm getting null when I set it to `Transaction` table?

```
Rctransaction rctransaction = new Rctransaction();
    rctransaction.getReceivings().getId().setId(id); // here id has value 
    rctransaction.getReceivings().getId().setBarcode(barcode);
    rctransaction.setReceivings(receivings);
```

Here are classes :
Receivings.java

```
public class Receivings  implements java.io.Serializable {


     private ReceivingsId id;
     private Suppliers suppliers;
     private String itemName;
     private String category;
     private double wholesalePrice;
     private double retailPrice;
     private long tax1;
     private long tax2;
     private String type1;
     private String type2;
     private int quantityStock;
     private int receivingQuantity;
     private int recorderLevel;
     private String receivingDate;
     private double discount;
     private Set itemses = new HashSet(0);
     private Set rctransactions = new HashSet(0);

    public Receivings() {
    }


    public Receivings(ReceivingsId id, Suppliers suppliers, String itemName, String category, double wholesalePrice, double retailPrice, long tax1, long tax2, String type1, String type2, int quantityStock, int receivingQuantity, int recorderLevel, String receivingDate, double discount) {
        this.id = id;
        this.suppliers = suppliers;
        this.itemName = itemName;
        this.category = category;
        this.wholesalePrice = wholesalePrice;
        this.retailPrice = retailPrice;
        this.tax1 = tax1;
        this.tax2 = tax2;
        this.type1 = type1;
        this.type2 = type2;
        this.quantityStock = quantityStock;
        this.receivingQuantity = receivingQuantity;
        this.recorderLevel = recorderLevel;
        this.receivingDate = receivingDate;
        this.discount = discount;
    }
    public Receivings(ReceivingsId id, Suppliers suppliers, String itemName, String category, double wholesalePrice, double retailPrice, long tax1, long tax2, String type1, String type2, int quantityStock, int receivingQuantity, int recorderLevel, String receivingDate, double discount, Set itemses, Set rctransactions) {
       this.id = id;
       this.suppliers = suppliers;
       this.itemName = itemName;
       this.category = category;
       this.wholesalePrice = wholesalePrice;
       this.retailPrice = retailPrice;
       this.tax1 = tax1;
       this.tax2 = tax2;
       this.type1 = type1;
       this.type2 = type2;
       this.quantityStock = quantityStock;
       this.receivingQuantity = receivingQuantity;
       this.recorderLevel = recorderLevel;
       this.receivingDate = receivingDate;
       this.discount = discount;
       this.itemses = itemses;
       this.rctransactions = rctransactions;
    }

    public ReceivingsId getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(ReceivingsId id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public Suppliers getSuppliers() {
        return this.suppliers;
    }

    public void setSuppliers(Suppliers suppliers) {
        this.suppliers = suppliers;
    }
    public String getItemName() {
        return this.itemName;
    }

    public void setItemName(String itemName) {
        this.itemName = itemName;
    }
    public String getCategory() {
        return this.category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }
    public double getWholesalePrice() {
        return this.wholesalePrice;
    }

    public void setWholesalePrice(double wholesalePrice) {
        this.wholesalePrice = wholesalePrice;
    }
    public double getRetailPrice() {
        return this.retailPrice;
    }

    public void setRetailPrice(double retailPrice) {
        this.retailPrice = retailPrice;
    }
    public long getTax1() {
        return this.tax1;
    }

    public void setTax1(long tax1) {
        this.tax1 = tax1;
    }
    public long getTax2() {
        return this.tax2;
    }

    public void setTax2(long tax2) {
        this.tax2 = tax2;
    }
    public String getType1() {
        return this.type1;
    }

    public void setType1(String type1) {
        this.type1 = type1;
    }
    public String getType2() {
        return this.type2;
    }

    public void setType2(String type2) {
        this.type2 = type2;
    }
    public int getQuantityStock() {
        return this.quantityStock;
    }

    public void setQuantityStock(int quantityStock) {
        this.quantityStock = quantityStock;
    }
    public int getReceivingQuantity() {
        return this.receivingQuantity;
    }

    public void setReceivingQuantity(int receivingQuantity) {
        this.receivingQuantity = receivingQuantity;
    }
    public int getRecorderLevel() {
        return this.recorderLevel;
    }

    public void setRecorderLevel(int recorderLevel) {
        this.recorderLevel = recorderLevel;
    }
    public String getReceivingDate() {
        return this.receivingDate;
    }

    public void setReceivingDate(String receivingDate) {
        this.receivingDate = receivingDate;
    }
    public double getDiscount() {
        return this.discount;
    }

    public void setDiscount(double discount) {
        this.discount = discount;
    }
    public Set getItemses() {
        return this.itemses;
    }

    public void setItemses(Set itemses) {
        this.itemses = itemses;
    }
    public Set getRctransactions() {
        return this.rctransactions;
    }

    public void setRctransactions(Set rctransactions) {
        this.rctransactions = rctransactions;
    }   
}
```

ReceivingsId.java

```
//Composition of Id and Barcode of Receivings  
public class ReceivingsId  implements java.io.Serializable {


     private int id;
     private int barcode;

    public ReceivingsId() {
    }

    public ReceivingsId(int id, int barcode) {
       this.id = id;
       this.barcode = barcode;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public int getBarcode() {
        return this.barcode;
    }

    public void setBarcode(int barcode) {
        this.barcode = barcode;
    }


   public boolean equals(Object other) {
         if ( (this == other ) ) return true;
         if ( (other == null ) ) return false;
         if ( !(other instanceof ReceivingsId) ) return false;
         ReceivingsId castOther = ( ReceivingsId ) other; 

         return (this.getId()==castOther.getId())
 && (this.getBarcode()==castOther.getBarcode());
   }

   public int hashCode() {
         int result = 17;

         result = 37 * result + this.getId();
         result = 37 * result + this.getBarcode();
         return result;
   }   
}
```

Rctransaction.java

```
public class Rctransaction  implements java.io.Serializable {


     private Integer id;
     private Receivings receivings;
     private String transaction;
     private String supplierName;
     private String itemName;
     private double quantity;
     private String paymentType;
     private double amountTendred;
     private double due;
     private double total;
     private double price;
     private int recorderLevel;

    public Rctransaction() {
    }

    public Rctransaction(Receivings receivings, String transaction, String supplierName, String itemName, double quantity, String paymentType, double amountTendred, double due, double total, double price, int recorderLevel) {
       this.receivings = receivings;
       this.transaction = transaction;
       this.supplierName = supplierName;
       this.itemName = itemName;
       this.quantity = quantity;
       this.paymentType = paymentType;
       this.amountTendred = amountTendred;
       this.due = due;
       this.total = total;
       this.price = price;
       this.recorderLevel = recorderLevel;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public Receivings getReceivings() {
        return this.receivings;
    }

    public void setReceivings(Receivings receivings) {
        this.receivings = receivings;
    }
    public String getTransaction() {
        return this.transaction;
    }

    public void setTransaction(String transaction) {
        this.transaction = transaction;
    }
    public String getSupplierName() {
        return this.supplierName;
    }

    public void setSupplierName(String supplierName) {
        this.supplierName = supplierName;
    }
    public String getItemName() {
        return this.itemName;
    }

    public void setItemName(String itemName) {
        this.itemName = itemName;
    }
    public double getQuantity() {
        return this.quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(double quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }
    public String getPaymentType() {
        return this.paymentType;
    }

    public void setPaymentType(String paymentType) {
        this.paymentType = paymentType;
    }
    public double getAmountTendred() {
        return this.amountTendred;
    }

    public void setAmountTendred(double amountTendred) {
        this.amountTendred = amountTendred;
    }
    public double getDue() {
        return this.due;
    }

    public void setDue(double due) {
        this.due = due;
    }
    public double getTotal() {
        return this.total;
    }

    public void setTotal(double total) {
        this.total = total;
    }
    public double getPrice() {
        return this.price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
    public int getRecorderLevel() {
        return this.recorderLevel;
    }

    public void setRecorderLevel(int recorderLevel) {
        this.recorderLevel = recorderLevel;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your table structure is not clear, can you post the `Recieving` and `Rctransaction` classes?

Comment: @JosepOriolSolerCatalà Ok I'll do.

Comment: @SwapnilNagtilak I've edited my previous answer. Hope it helps!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are instantiating the Hibernate objects in the wrong order.

First you need a ReceivingsId :

```
ReceivingsId rid = new ReceivingsId (id, barcode);
```

Then add this `rid` to a `Receivings`:

```
Receivings rec = new Receivings();
rec.setId(rid);
```

And finally set it to the `Rctransaction`:

```
Rctransaction rctransaction = new Rctransaction();
rctransaction.setReceivings(rec);
```

If you try to call `getReceivings` after instantiating the object without setting it before you'll always get a NullPointerException. To avoid this, you can instantiate the `Receivings` object in the `Rctransaction` constructor.

Comment: Ok I'll try this.

Comment: @SwapnilNagtilak Did the answer solve your question? In that case if you have another doubt you should post another question to make it easier to find to someone with the same problem. Actually comments are only for clarification and I think that your doubt requires a more extensive explanation.

Comment: Can you post the trace of the exception?

Comment: @SwapnilNagtilak Yes, I could understand that after you posted the classes, but what I say is that when you are instantiating a `Rctransaction` receivings is null and calling `getReceivings` will throw a NPE. Another option is to add `this.receivings = new Receivings();` to the default constructor of `Rctransaction` and `this.id = new ReceivingsId();` to the default constructor of `Receivings`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186191/discussion-between-josep-oriol-soler-catala-and-swapnil-nagtilak).

Comment: can you please help me solve this issue [Unable to convertRowIndexToModel in jTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53971739/unable-to-convertrowindextomodel-in-jtable)